# Error Trying to Use Data Factory SFTP Connector as Sink

Tags: azure, sftp, file-transfer, azure-data-factory

So Azure just recently [announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sftp#sftp-as-sink) that SFTP can be used as a sink in Data Factory.

I have been trying to test this functionality in Azure Government.

- Data Factory copies a single file from blob storage to an SFTP server.
- Blob storage with delimited file as source, with SFTP location as sink.
- I have white listed the integration runtime for the SFTP server.

I get the following error when trying to run the copy activity:

```
{ 
"errorCode": "2200", "message": "Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=UserErrorSftpPermissionDenied,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Permission
 denied to access '/C:/Users/rmsftp/Documents/_SUCCESS.txt.82a1f514a859473ea2c764dadedc9713'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPermissionDeniedException,Message=Permission denied,Source=Renci.SshNet,'",
 "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy data1", "details": [] 
}
```

Any tips on how to solve this issue would be awesome.

Note that part of the file actually gets copied over. But not the entire file and the activity still throws and error and says failed.